# Mysql table structure, a better solution

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

wonder if anyone could help me out. I have 2 tables, contacts & leads - Users insert new leads into these tables (leads + contacts joined by contactID) from a single form, works well enough albeit with extra coding to insert data into 2 tables and create the contactid into leads table before insert.

Is it better practice to merge these 2 tables into 1 so lead & contact information is stored in 1 table going forward, less coding aside I dont know why why so many examples suggest this is a better solution?

My concerns are with GDPR rules very close we need to set a contact delete date and a lead delete date which will always be different?

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Can you post your table schema ?  Also, I would recommend having separate tables which represent the different data.

Comment: I presume a contact is always a person. Is a lead always a *company*? Is there *never* more than one contact per lead? (A limit of one contact per company seems odd.)

Comment: A contact is always a person and the lead is the actual details of potential product sale (single). Each contact could have up to 10 leads

Answer (score 2):

Two tables are considered better because they offer a clean, normalized, data model when you need each `lead` row to have any number of `contact` rows (from zero to thousands).  There are zillions of tutorials on normalization. [Here is just one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics).

If, now and always, each `lead` has exactly one `contact`, you certainly can use one table.

If you need different privacy-purge dates for leads and contacts, you should put a timestamp column in each table. Then you can do stuff like this every night

```
   UPDATE contact 
      SET givenname='-purged-',
          surname='-purged-',
          addr='-purged-',
          phone='-purged-'
    WHERE input_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

and your personally identifiable information will disappear. (You could also DELETE the rows, but if you do think through your foreign key constraint situation first.)

If you have different purge rules for `contact` and `lead`, a two table structure makes this purging easy.

(Please notice that you didn't tell us your table definitions or exact purge rules, so the code here is based on my guesses, which are certainly wrong.)

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent answer, One contact could have up to 10 unique leads so I'm guessing the answer is 2 tables as it currently is.

Presently the tables are linked by contactID, so each contact could have several leads which I later pull through to display all leads by contact.

Msany thanks again., maybe Ill stick with 2 and just create the extra code to insert/update/edit from a single form..